# Force Ubuntu to boot in Legacy Mode only

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, mbr

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in an old system after wiping the disk clear of the previous dual boot of Ubuntu + Windows. After clearing the disk completely (including the EFI partitions) and installing the new Ubuntu version, the installation is completed as expected. Still, upon boot, the system cannot locate any OS on the disk.

I think the issue is that Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode and the system is trying to locate an OS in Legacy mode, which could be solved by switching the boot preference to UEFI, but in my case, the Boot Menu is locked with a password and there is no way for me to switch the preference to UEFI in the boot menu.

Would it be possible to force the Ubuntu to boot in Legacy Mode?

Here is the disk-repair report if that would be of any help: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vfn7KFR8cY/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt3)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 68SSU Ver. F.21(15.33) from Hewlett-Packard
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).


a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda2/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/BOOT/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda3    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda3    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda3    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk identifier: 5CA8A647-DAB7-42B3-B71A-2A85B0258980
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   1054719   1050624   513M EFI System
sda3  1054720 625141759 624087040 297.6G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 14.46 GiB, 15525216256 bytes, 30322688 sectors
Disk identifier: F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876F-C8245AF921E0
       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  9828451  9828388  4.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9828452  9838519    10068  4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9838520  9839119      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9842688 30322624 20479937  9.8G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:320GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA HITACHI HTS54323:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:540MB:538MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:540MB:320GB:320GB:ext4::;
sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:hp v301w:;
1:32.8kB:5032MB:5032MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:5032MB:5037MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:5037MB:5038MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:5039MB:15.5GB:10.5GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1                                               599c001f-183e-4bc7-a519-2014ac40cb19                          
├─sda2 vfat     A27C-67AF                            d38dfae1-60c1-4e50-9eaa-6630ca638dfe                          EFI System Partition
└─sda3 ext4     dbbea994-f196-496c-9f3c-001e3503ca87 686b7161-d7ef-4388-b29b-067d52f28771                          
sdb    iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2023-08-08-01-19-05-00               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     F7DB-4D56                            f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876c-c8245af921e0                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     5059423a-6013-4bf1-a0f2-18a2180bd6f4 91426e3f-0824-ee48-b8a6-5d7336785176 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                                                     505.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                                                     263.7G   5% /target
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2                                                     vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda3                                                     ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid dbbea994-f196-496c-9f3c-001e3503ca87 root hd0,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   dbbea994-f196-496c-9f3c-001e3503ca87
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda3/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=dbbea994-f196-496c-9f3c-001e3503ca87 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=A27C-67AF  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 158.939720154 = 170.660225024  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 159.129451752 = 170.863947776  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  11.766181946 = 12.633841664   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  10.263324738 = 11.020161024   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic                  2
  11.766181946 = 12.633841664   boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic                  1
  10.263324738 = 11.020161024   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 215.739784241 = 231.648829440  boot/initrd.img                                1
 215.449123383 = 231.336734720  boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic               1
 215.739784241 = 231.648829440  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic               1
 215.449123383 = 231.336734720  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 19  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 19  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 19  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 19  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 19  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 19  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 19  2022 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda3,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

/target detected. Please close the Ubuntu installer, then retry. The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS entry (sda2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
```

Comment: @DanielT Looks like it might work, will try some of the solutions from there and update the post.